# Cannot call function stored in unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I tried to make `call_function` take a string argument and call the function that corresponds to that string in the map, but I get an error. How do I fix this? Why doesn't it work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class xyz {
public:
    unordered_map< std::string, void(xyz::*)()> arr{
        { "user", &xyz::func_user},
        { "pwd", &xyz::func_pwd},
        { "dir", &xyz::func_dir}
    };

    void call_function(std::string x) {
        arr.at( x)();// Error: term does not evaluate a function taking 0 arguments
    }

    void func_user(){
        cout << "func_user" << endl;
    }

    void func_pwd(){
        cout << "func_pwd" << endl;
    }

    void func_dir(){
        cout << "func_dir" << endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    xyz a;

    a.call_function( "dir");
}
```

Comment: It is not a function, it is a pointer to a member function.

Comment: You appear to have mixed class member functions up with global functions.   The class member functions need a class instance to work.

Comment: `arr` is a public member variable of `xyz`. You shouldn't be able to access it from `call_function()` in the code you've written. Please show us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values in `arr` are pointers to non-static member functions of class `xyz`, so in order to call them, you need an `xyz` object.

When you call a member function directly, you can usually omit the `this->`. However, when you call through a pointer to member, you cannot omit `this->*`. You have to write it explicitly:

```
(this->*arr.at(x))();
```

Comment: This will make the code compile, but it's still sub-par. You need to test the result of `arr.at()` versus `arr.end()` and take some action if there's no match.